# wubi installed Ubuntu 12.04 in Windows XP not to open

Tags: 12.04, wubi, system-installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 with Wubi installer according to the proper instructions
and  when restarted I am not able to start Ubuntu.

It is installed in the `D:` drive in Windows XP. When restarting I have only access to Windows XP.

How can I boot into Ubuntu?

Comment: You should get ride of Windows XP and [install Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/6328/62483) as the only system.

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows environment The D drive is typically the first optical drive seen by Windows. Have you changed your drive letter assignments within Windows? If you installed from Wubi then you should see a screen at boot up asking what OS you would like to boot into. Go into your add/remove programs within Windows and see if Wubi is listed. If not then the install was not a success.